# Get code from protected excel doc

Tags: excel

Is it possible to get function or script code from a protected excel document? 
If so, how do I go about doing this?

The file is .xls and was likely created in office 2003

Answer (score 2):

for 2007 you can always buy third party software to unlock the VBA Project.

Or, you can do it yourself. I only know the very messy way - rename your file from .xlsm to .zip, and accept windows telling you this may cause bother. Then, go into your new zip, and you will find your .bin file (default name is vbaProject.bin unless the original author changed it). Copy it, and paste it somewhere else to keep the original document intact. Then, open up the bin file in notepad ++ and patiently scour your way through until you find your code. Even if the project is password protected, it will all be in here, but may require a little patience.

Comment: Not really, I think we just ended up tracking down the original work document, and unlocking it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version excel document it is.  The older excel documents (2003) can easily be accessed even if they are encrypted, but encrypted 2007 excel documents are much more difficult to open if you have forgotten the password.

Comment: It's a .xls document. And I would bet that it's created in MSO 2003 because it's really old.